# Strip a tag in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<Tag1>
<dummy><name>qwert</name><id>123</id></dummy>
<dummy><name>wert</name><id>023</id></dummy>
<dummy><name>hfj</name><id>103</id></dummy>    
</Tag1>
```

I have above XML for which I want to strip the   in the XML output file

Desired O/p:

```
<Tag1>
<name>qwert</name><id>123</id>
<name>wert</name><id>023</id>
<name>hfj</name><id>103</id>   
</Tag1>
```

Also I tried using the below XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
 <xsl:copy>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="dummy"/>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's removing  as well everything underneath it

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this instead, to ensure the children of `dummy` are still selected

```
 <xsl:template match="dummy">
   <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:template>
```

EDIT: Here is the complete spreadsheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dummy">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I used `code`<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:template match="dummy">
   <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>`code`. But it strips all the tags and my output is now qwert and 123 in seperate lines

Comment: @tradersjoe Keep the *identity transform* template (your 1st template) and replace your 2nd template (the one matching `dummy`) with the template suggested above.

Comment: @tradersjoe - I've edited my answer to show the complete stylesheet